Debugging a Dll that being injected to a process by injector. We have the original pdb symbol and source of Dll and the target process

I have a dll named dll.dll and its symbol dll.pdb. I use injector injector.exe to inject dll.dll to target process target_process.exe and I also have target process.pdb.
In dll.dll, I set a __asm{int 0x3;} breakppoint.
I already set symbol for target_process.exe's debug session point to location of dll.pdb, and set source location to dll.dll's source code.
In target_process.exe's debug session, when the injector.exe create remote thread that run dll.dll in target_process.exe (target_process.exe has started and is waiting for user input to continue), the breakpoint hit and i am sure that dll.dll has been successfully injected, executed, and its __asm{int 0x3;} instruction punched windbg, but windbg just show the breakpoint is hit at instruction int 0x03, not show the source of dll.dll.
Here I am using Microsoft visual studio 2022 x86 debug build to build things, and windbg x86 to debug
Please help me make windbg recognize dll.dll's symbol and source in target_process.exe's debug session, or may be making dll.dll's symbol and source cooperate with target_process.exe's symbol and source.


does lm vm dll list the DLL?

lm vm dll didn't list the dll (here named "reflective_dll.dll"), event the messageBox of the Dll poped-up. I am trying to implement reflective dll injection technique, which the injector createremote thread of the exported reflective loader module of the reflective_dll.dll
